# Почему в QListWidget не отображается кастомный виджет?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qlistwidget

Помогите разобраться, в чём причина отсутствия отображения виджета в `QListWidget`.

Пробовал добавлять отдельно виджет `QLabel`, но увы не вышло.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Message(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, text):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M' + ', ' + name + ':')  # получение строки с данными о сообщении

        # установка виджетов
        self.info = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.data)
        self.info.resize(20, 100)
        self.info.move(0, 5)

        self.info = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
        self.info.resize(20, 100)
        self.info.move(35, 5)

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)
        self.send_btn.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        custom_item = Message('Name', self.mes_input.text())

        self.messages_panel.addItem(item)
        self.messages_panel.setItemWidget(item, custom_item)
        self.mes_input.setText('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**untitled.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>730</width>
    <height>516</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="send_btn">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>630</x>
      <y>420</y>
      <width>91</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="mes_input">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>420</y>
      <width>601</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QListWidget" name="messages_panel">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>701</width>
      <height>401</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>730</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
#from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Message(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, text, parent=None):
        super(Message, self).__init__(parent)
        
        # получение строки с данными о сообщении
#        self.data = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M' + ', ' + name + ':')  
        self.data = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString(' hh:mm ')+ name
        
        self.iconLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        self.iconLabel.setMinimumSize(80, 80)
        self.iconLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('lena.jpg').scaled(80, 80))        
        
        self.info = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.data)    
        self.info_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(2, 1, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.iconLabel, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.info, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.info_2, 1, 1)
        self.layout.setSpacing(1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)
        self.send_btn.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.mes_input.setFocus()

    def run(self):
        custom_item = Message('Lena', self.mes_input.text(), self)  
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.messages_panel)        
        item.setSizeHint(custom_item.sizeHint())
        self.messages_panel.addItem(item)
        self.messages_panel.setItemWidget(item, custom_item)
        self.mes_input.setText('')
        self.mes_input.setFocus()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]